# How can i call C# method from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying parse parameter from javaScript to C# method in asp.net

```
function handleClick(event) {
       var id=event.item.values.value;
       alert(<%MyMethod("id")%>);
    }
```

it give me nothing

Comment: JavaScript is running in the browser. C# is running on the server. You need to use ajax to go between the two.

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to accomplish here?

Comment: You wouldn't call C# method from Javascript (at least in your context of ASP pages)

Comment: @MattBall How can i do that?

Comment: The block in between `<%` and `%>` only runs on the server and it sends down to the client. It's one way. You can't use that to send stuff back. You need to do a form with a POST or make a url with a query string to get data back to the server.